# Setting up wireless headset to connect with PC via wireles access point

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, audio

I need to use a wireless headset (microphone + earphones) to connect with my PC from a distance that is out of normal range.  Is there a way to use a wireless router as an access point to boost the signal?  I would prefer to use a Bluetooth headset to connect to my PC because they are much less expensive than a PC headset. Is this an option?  Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wireless access point you use to browse the internet is not the same wireless technology as Bluetooth, which can be used to connect peripherals to computers. They are both radio waves, but they operate using different protocols on different frequencies. They essentially speak different languages.

Wireless keyboards, etc, can also work via infra-red which doesn't use radio waves at all and requires line of sight between both devices.

> Wi-Fi is often referred to as "wireless internet", because that's what
>   it is most often used for, accessing the internet. When you see people
>   surfing the web in a cafe, they're probably using Wi-Fi.
>
> Bluetooth technology is in lots of the devices that you already have and can be
>   used for all sorts of things. It works for both voice–like talking
>   hands-free on a headset or speakerphone–and data like pictures, music
>   and documents.

[1](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Wi-Fi.aspx)

Having said that I see no reason why someone couldn't bundle the technology with a wireless access point. I had a brief google search for Bluetooth wireless access points, as this is not something I have come across before and wasn't able to find any clear Bluetooth products.

If you have a USB bluetooth "dongle", there is no reason why you couldn't plug into a powered USB hub, or use a USB extension cable to give it some more distance from your computer.
This wouldn't repeat the signal from different locations like a WiFi network though.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable insight. I need this wireless headset for a warehouse work environment for 3 different users . Is it  practical to have multiple USB bluetooth dongles, so the 3 different bluetooth headsets can functon throughout the warehouse? if no, and I need to use a PC wireless headset, what is the procedure to settup the router access points to communicate between  the headset and to each user's PC?